# Exposing docker container on local server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a nodejs-mongo db app that is running inside docker containers.
I can access it on localhost etc...

But now I would like to install/deploy these containers on a local server, so that I can access this application outside my network.
Please note my server is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (xenial)

Also I would like to access Db from outside, so that I can send data to the Db using custom script.

I am newbie in both networking and Docker. As a result I am struggling to understand what needs to be done. Any pointers would be appreciated

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        volumes: # Use this to mount app from local disk
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "5858:5858"
        entrypoint: node --debug=5858 app.js
        links:
            - mongo
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Usual command that I give to start my containers `docker-compose up --build -d`

Here is `docker ps` result

```
"node --debug=5858 ap"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:5858->5858/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   nodemongochart_web_1

"/entrypoint.sh mongo"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                         nodemongochart_mongo_1
```

Comment: Your dockerfile and docker-compose.yml seem solid and should work. Where is your local server placed at? How are you accessing it?

Comment: I have been provisioned one office ubuntu machine. So not sure about its setup. I am accessing it using ssh certificate. If there is something specific to know that would be useful, I can ask the guy who assigned me this machine

Answer (score 0):

If by local server, you mean your own machine at home, you will need to do something called "Port Forwarding".
It's usually configurable in your router, and you'll be able to access your application via some kind of link like this :

```
http://you-personal-ip:8080
```

If you'll be using another host, not in your own network, they should provide you with an IP address, in that case, no need for port forwarding.

Comment: ok its a machine somewhere in our office network. I am accessing using ssh with following command `ssh -i <certfile> <user>@<serverip>. I have tried accessing the app using http://<serverip>:8080. But it "timesout" when opening in my browser.

Comment: Make sure the port 8080 is accessible in that machine. There is a good chance that the firewall is blocking it (iptables)